# Java Thread - i want to generate numbers in sequence eg: 1,2,3,4...so on (there will be 2 threads only )

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, number-sequence

Java Thread - i want to generate numbers in sequence eg: 1,2,3,4... (there will be 2 threads only ) 1st thread o/p will be 1 ,second thread o/p will be 2 , again 1st thread o/p will be 3 and so on , it can be upto 10 or upto n number whatever just wanna get the logic please help me guys :|

below is my attempt to do it but its not working i know there would be wait() and notify() methods for sure but cant figure out the proper way to use them !

class NumberGenerator
{
    static int number = 0;

```
synchronized public int numGenerator()
{
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
        number=i;
    }
    return number;
}
```

}

class FirstThreadClass extends Thread
{
    NumberGenerator num;

```
FirstThreadClass(NumberGenerator num)
{
    this.num = num;
}

public void run()
{
    System.out.println("i am from 1st thread :"+num.numGenerator());

}
```

}

class SecondThreadClass extends Thread
{
    NumberGenerator num;

```
SecondThreadClass(NumberGenerator num)
{
    this.num = num;
}

public void run()
{
    System.out.println("i am from 2nd thread :"+num.numGenerator());
}
```

}

public class ThreadTesting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    FirstThreadClass ftc = new FirstThreadClass(new NumberGenerator());
    SecondThreadClass stc = new SecondThreadClass(new NumberGenerator());
    ftc.start();
    stc.start();
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried already?

Comment: The whole point of having concurrent threads is to allow independant task to perform at the same time. If you have this requirement it is telling not to use threads, as the tasks are dependant on each other.

Answer (score 1):

```
    class NumberGenerator
    {
        static int counter = 0;

        public synchronized int getNextNumber()
        {
            return counter++;
        }


    }
    class FirstThreadClass
        extends Thread
    {
        NumberGenerator num;

        FirstThreadClass(NumberGenerator num)
        {
            this.num = num;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            System.out.println("i am from 1st thread :" + num.getNextNumber());

        }


    }
    class SecondThreadClass
        extends Thread
    {
        NumberGenerator num;

        SecondThreadClass(NumberGenerator num)
        {
            this.num = num;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            System.out.println("i am from 2nd thread :" + num.getNextNumber());
        }


    }

    public class ThreadTesting
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            FirstThreadClass ftc = new FirstThreadClass(new NumberGenerator());
            SecondThreadClass stc = new SecondThreadClass(new NumberGenerator());
            for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
            {
                ftc.run();
                stc.run();
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: you are calling thread's run method and not start, it is same as calling some method manually. Question is two print the sequence with two threads

Answer (score 0):

You can have each thread generate numbers as follows:

```
Thread 1: 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, ...
Thread 2: 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, ...
```

add to a concurrent collection and sort afterwards.

Comment: this was asked in an interview which i couldn't able to answer...from yesterday i am trying to figure out the solution :|

Comment: @peter lawrey hi peter thanks for the comment yes i know what you are saying but i cant argue with the interviewer :P he asked me this so i had to answer it anyways :(

Answer (score 0):

Do they have to generate only one each time, or is it ok if thread1 generate 2 numbers, then thread 2 generates 1 number etc... ?

Use a static int field that will act as a counter, and access it in a synchronized way.

```
static int counter = 0;

public synchronized int getNextNumber(){
  return counter++;
}
```

Then the threads do :

```
while(...whatever..){
  System.out.print(getNextNumber());
}
```

Comment: hmm i have tried your logic its printing o/p as :                    i am from 1st thread :0
i am from 2nd thread :1

Comment: Yes, is it not what you wanted?

Comment: i want it to print number sequence upto n but its printing only 1,2 how can i apply wait() and notify() so that once threadone print 1 and will get into wait() state then threadtwo print 2 then it will notify threadone and it itself will go into wait() state ,threadone print 3...and so on ..

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using cyclic barrier, create a barrier and once two threads have generated one number each print the two numbers

```
class ThreadTest {

    private CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier = new CyclicBarrier(2, new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(oddNumberGenerator.result);
            System.out.println(evenNumberGenerator.result);
        }
    });

    private NumberGenerator oddNumberGenerator = new NumberGenerator(1,11,2);
    private NumberGenerator evenNumberGenerator = new NumberGenerator(2,10,2);

    public void generateSeries(){
        oddNumberGenerator.generateNumbers();
        evenNumberGenerator.generateNumbers();
    }


    class NumberGenerator {
        private Thread thread;
        private int result;

        private NumberGenerator(final int initialValue, final int maxValue,
                                final int stepSize) {
            this.thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = initialValue; i <= maxValue; i = i + stepSize) {
                        try {
                            result = i;
                            cyclicBarrier.await();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public void generateNumbers() {
            thread.start();
        }
    }


    main(String[] args){
       new ThreadTest().generateSeries();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve using wait and notifyAll() . But it is always better to use standard java concurrent classes to achieve it

```
public class PrintAlternateValues {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final NumberValue number = new NumberValue();
        final Object lockObject = new Object();
        new Thread(){

            private NumberValue n  = number;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized (lockObject) {
                    while(n.getValue() < n.getEndPoint()){
                        while(n.isToggle()){
                            try{
                                lockObject.wait();
                            }catch(Exception e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        n.incrementValue();
                        System.out.println(getName() + " printing "+n.getValue());
                        n.setToggle(true);
                        lockObject.notifyAll();
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();

        new Thread(){

            private NumberValue n  = number;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized (lockObject) {
                    while(n.getValue() < n.getEndPoint()){
                        while(!n.isToggle()){
                            try{
                                lockObject.wait();
                            }catch(Exception e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        n.incrementValue();
                        System.out.println(getName() + " printing "+n.getValue());
                        n.setToggle(false);
                        lockObject.notifyAll();
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}

class NumberValue {
    private int value;
    private boolean toggle = true;
    private int endPoint = 10;

    public int getEndPoint() {
        return endPoint;
    }

    public void setEndPoint(int endPoint) {
        this.endPoint = endPoint;
    }

    public boolean isToggle() {
        return toggle;
    }

    public void setToggle(boolean toggle) {
        this.toggle = toggle;
    }

    public  int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public synchronized void incrementValue(){
        this.value++; 
    }
}
```